# React Js / using setTimout on jsx with state

Tags: reactjs

Hello i have a chat bot and i am trying to simulate a typing bot

that is, I have a component where I send my text as props and then I wanted to use a settimout on it to display the text after a while and hide the typing animation

but i got problem with this like this:

[image]

this number appeared, which is not my answer and he also repeatedly executes my settimout
I can no longer imagine how I will simulate typing animation with this

my store redux

action:

```
export const ON_MESSAGE = 'ON_MESSAGE';
export const BOT_MESSAGE = 'BOT_MESSAGE';
export const AWAIT_MESSAGE = 'AWAIT_MESSAGE';
export const FINISH = 'FINISH';
export const sendMessage = text => ({
  type: ON_MESSAGE,
  text,
});

export const botMessage = text => ({
  type: BOT_MESSAGE,
  text,
});

export const checkMessage = text => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(sendMessage(text));
    dispatch(botMessage(verify(text)));
  };
};
```

my reducer:

```
const initalState = {
  messages: [],
  waitResponse: false,
  bot: false,
};

const messageReducer = (state = initalState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ON_MESSAGE:
      return {
        ...state,
        messages: [
          ...state.messages,
          {
            type: 'user',
            text: action.text,
            date: moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY-h:mm:ss'),
          },
        ],
        waitResponse: true,
        bot: true,
      };

    case BOT_MESSAGE:
      return {
        ...state,
        messages: [
          ...state.messages,
          {
            type: 'bot',
            text: action.text,
            date: moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY-h:mm:ss'),
          },
        ],
        waitResponse: false,
      };
    case FINISH:
      return [
        {
          ...state,
          waitResponse: false,
        },
      ];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

and my jsx:

```
 <Styled.ChatLog>
        {chat.messages.map((rowData, index) => (
          <Styled.MessageFlexColumn key={index}>
            {rowData.type === 'user' ? (
              <UserText key={index}>{rowData.text}</UserText>
            ) : (
              <BotText key={index}>{rowData.text}</BotText>
            )}
            <div ref={messagesEndRef} />
            <Styled.Status />
          </Styled.MessageFlexColumn>
        ))}
        <div ref={messagesEndRef} />
      </Styled.ChatLog>
```

my UserText component and botText component:

```
const BotText = props => {
  const [text, setText] = useState(['']);
  const [showText, setShow] = useState(false);
  const getText = () => {
    setShow(!showText);
    return props.children;
  };
  return (
    <Styled.MessageWrapper>
      <Styled.BotImg src={BotLogo} />
      <Styled.ChatMessage>
        <Styled.TypingWrapper show={showText}>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </Styled.TypingWrapper>
        {setTimeout(() => {
          getText();
        }, 3000)}
      </Styled.ChatMessage>
    </Styled.MessageWrapper>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres room for improvement here, but basically this should work. Whenever the text property changes it will show the typing animation for 3 seconds, then switch to the updated text

```
const BotText = props => {
  const {text} = props;
  const memoedText = useMemo(() => text, []);
  const [isTyping, setIsTyping] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      setIsTyping(false);
    }, [3000]);

    return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  }, [])

  return (
    <Styled.MessageWrapper>
      <Styled.BotImg src={BotLogo} />
      <Styled.ChatMessage>
        <Styled.TypingWrapper show={isTyping}>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </Styled.TypingWrapper>
        {!isTyping && memoedText}
      </Styled.ChatMessage>
    </Styled.MessageWrapper>
  );
};
```

EDIT per the reply converstation:

```
const ChatLog = props => {
  const { chat } = props;
  const { messages } = chat;
  const [isTyping, setIsTyping] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (messages[messages.length - 1].type === "bot") {
      setIsTyping(true);
      const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        setIsTyping(false);
      }, 3000);
    }
  }, [messages]);

  return (
    <div>
      {messages.map((message, idx) => {
        return message.type === "user" ? 
          <UserText key={idx}>
            {message.text}
          </UserText> : 
          <BotText 
            key={idx} 
            isTyping={isTyping && idx === messages.length - 1}
          >
            {message.text}
          </BotText

      }}
    </div>
  )
}

const BotText = props => {
  if (props.isTyping) return <div>typing stuff here</div>
  return <div>normal non-typing message render logic here</div>
}
```

Comment: I did it like this and I had a problem typing a new text the old one also remakes the animation

Comment: okay, try changing the places where I did `[text]` to just `[]`

Comment: oh sorry my bad Could I edit the response with my action and reducer for you to see if there is any possibility of doing something like this with the reducer?

Comment: Sure, but personally I think this type of behavior would be handled better within the component

Comment: Really, I spent hours thinking about it and I found this one option, I will edit my action and reducer and my jsx if you can tell me where I can improve

Comment: After reading your updates, I'm not really sure I'll be able to help you multiple much, sorry. It might work better though if in the the `ChatLog` you keep the `isTyping` state, setting it to true (and the `useEffect`/`setTimout` logic to switch it to false) it whenever a new bot message comes in, then pass that boolean into the last `BotText` component

Comment: I could not understand

Comment: I updated my response again, it still isn't using the Redux reducer to handle the typing though, I'm not sure the best way to do that.